# Create a mixin and use it within the same SASS loop

Tags: css, sass

I have a SASS loop that generates 'utility' style classes for margin top as the designer works in increments of 8px / .5 rem.

I have decided to sharpen up on my SASS skills here and created a loop to output this as classes:

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    .mt-#{$i} {
        margin-top: #{(($i * 8) / 16)}rem;
    }
}
```

However, I also want to create a mixin at the same time so that I can either directly use the class in the markup or include it via @include.

I tried:

```
@for $i from 1 through 12 {
    @mixin margin-top-#{$i} {
        margin-top: #{(($i * 8) / 16)}rem;
    }
    .mt-#{$i} {
        @include margin-top-#{$i}();
    }
}
```

This gave me a syntax error the mixin declaration line. Is this possible to do? Or should I just make two loops seeing as it will output the same?

Comment: Unfortunately, mixins can't be declared inside for-loops. Nor can their names be interpolated.